# Ruby/Rails testing - access variable outside of scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I want to unit test a method with rspec for RoR and have a method like this:

```
def create_record(obj, params)
    begin
      obj.add_attributes(params)
      result = obj.save
    rescue
      MyMailer.failed_upload(@other_var, obj.api_class_name, params).deliver_now
    end
end
```

`create_record` is never invoked directly, but through another method which fills in `@other_var` appropriately.

How should I go about testing the code to make sure MyMailer is called correctly? Should I have passed `@other_var` into the method instead of relying on it being filled in elsewhere (aka: is this a code smell?)? Thanks!

Comment: stub `obj.save` to raise some error and check if `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count` is increased by one.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can use [`Object#instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to set any instance variable.

```
RSpec.describe Thing do 
  describe "#create_record" do
    let(:thing) do
      t = Thing.new
      t.instance_variable_set(:@other_var, "foo")
      t
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

This completely circumvents any encapsulation which means that the use of `instance_variable_set` can be considered a code smell.

Another alternative is to use RSpecs mocking and stubbing facilities but stubbing the actual object under test is also a code smell.

You can avoid this by passing the dependency as a parameter or by constructor injection:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :other_var

  def initialize(other_var: nil)
     @other_var = other_var
  end

  def create_record(obj, attributes)
     # ...
  end
end
```

A good pattern for this is [service objects](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services).

Comment: So I should have passed this in as a parameter to `create_record` to begin with? Is that the major take away? Thanks!

Comment: Yes pretty much.

Comment: Another big issue with the code provided is that you are using a catch-all `rescue` statement without providing the exceptions you want to rescue. This masks bugs in the program.